# ffmpeg: limiting to single CPU core when encoding h264

Tags: ffmpeg, video, cpu-usage, video-encoding

I need to reduce the framerate of some H.264 videos in the background without maxing out my CPU (on Linux). Somehow `-threads 1` has no effect at all:

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i 50fps.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 30fps.mp4
```

Stream info:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, progressive)
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D)
```

All the cores are still maxed out. How can I limit this to just one core? H.265 has an encoder-specific option for this (`pools=none`), is there anything similar I can use here?

Comment: For future readers, this example command line is super simplified, omitting `-c:a copy` so it also transcodes the audio (using FFmpeg's built-in AAC encoder that's generally  lowish-quality last I read), losing quality and costing CPU time.  And it uses the libx264 defaults of `-preset medium -crf 23`, so the quality per bitrate could be higher if you wanted to spend more CPU time, and you could spend more or less bitrate for more or less quality at similar encode speed.  And some content benefits from `-tune film`.  See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this with `taskset`:

```
taskset -c 0 ffmpeg ...
```

to run your ffmpeg process confined to the 1st CPU core (counting from 0). Or for example, to run it on the 1st and 3rd core:

```
taskset -c 0,2 ffmpeg ...
```

Comment: That works! 10+ years developing on Linux, and I didn't know this command. For the sake of completeness I'll wait for a "pure" ffmpeg answer before accepting this.

Comment: Interesting; libx264 somehow figures out (e.g. by checking its affinity mask) not to start the usual `cores * 1.5` threads when you use taskset, so you don't have tons of context-switches with this.  (And some per-thread memory which would have wasting memory bandwidth and L3 cache footprint.)

Comment: So you don't need to use `-threads:v 1` or `-x264-params "threads=1"` with this, it seems; libx264 infers that.  (But even with threads=1, ffmpeg still runs video encoding in a separate thread from audio + other stuff, and the main ffmpeg thread, so you might not want to force it to compete with itself for a single core.  With just threads=1, it uses about 108% of a single core, encoding 1080p at preset=medium crf23, and transcoding the audio instead of `-c:a copy`.)

Comment: For the sake of anybody who actually ends up here searching for similar questions, this particular answer works, but it may still have unexpected effects on the performance of the rest of the system (CPU scheduling does not pin tasks to cores by default for _very_ good reasons).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: So suppose I'm doing some heavy computations with multithreading and I want to pin a certain process with a certain CPU. Would that increase performance at all? I have a suspicion that my OS's (Mac or Linux) are shuffling my tasks around quite a bit, and I wonder if that hampers performance.

Comment: @AdrianKeister It _might_. The problem is that there are other things each CPU core actually has to do regularly. Tasks get shuffled around so that they can continue running when those other things that are inherently CPU specific happen, and pinning the task to one core does not get rid of them. SUSE Labs has an [excellent series of blog posts](https://www.suse.com/c/cpu-isolation-introduction-part-1/) that touches on this core-specific stuff and what all is involved in avoiding it on LInux, but in general this is chasing levels of optimization that really are not worth it for most users.

Answer (score 15):

Video encoding threads is set by output `-threads`.

So,

```
ffmpeg -i 50fps.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 -threads:v 1 30fps.mp4
```

Comment: This has the effect of reducing load but still distributing it to multiple cores. No single core is maxed out, but overall my 4 core CPU is running at ~50%. Maybe `taskset` is the only reliable way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg won't limit to specific cores. Also, output threads only limits encoding threads. There's decoding and filtering as well as the main program thread.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! For practical purposes (reducing load and keeping some cores fully available for other tasks) the answer is `taskset` then.

Comment: @kontextify that's normal and not bad. There's no benefit to keeping *specific* cores "available" versus letting the OS decide what's optimal at a given moment. If you

Comment: @hobbs - if you're trying to minimize interference with other processes, pinning to a single core _can_ be a good idea. Bouncing between cores can thrash L1 caches, for one. It's not a free lunch - there are other downsides to it - but that's not the same as saying that there are no upsides.

Comment: @kontextify Even if ffmpeg is only using a single thread, it's likely that your operating system's task scheduler is spreading the load out by switching which core the thread is executing on. Using `taskset` as described in Gordan Bobić's answer is a sure way to force ffmpeg to only execute on one single core, no matter how many threads it does or doesn't use.

Comment: @TLW Linux is already aware of that and will try to reschedule a task on the same core it recently ran on, but it will break that rule *for good reasons*. cpuset pinning does have its uses (especially for network apps) but this isn't really one of them. In particular, unless you give every *other* process on the system a cpumask, it doesn't protect the cache as much as you would think. The times when ffmpeg is hopping cores without `taskset` are going to be pretty much the times when *it wouldn't have helped* to put it back on the same core anyway.

Comment: @hobbs - CFS is pretty good; it's not perfect. It can't tell the difference between two tasks with the same overall working set, but one accessing memory in a predictable manner and the other accessing in an unpredictable manner, for instance.

Comment: You can move 1 thread from core to core to keep the heat down, so you can run It at higher clock speed.

Comment: @gnasher729 - assuming that the speed increase is more than the speed decrease from the decreased L1 $ hit rate every time you switch cores, yep. (Also TLB, branch prediction, etc...). Hm. Now I'm wondering about a processor architecture that saved/restored L1 cache state on thread switch... Probably not worth it, but interesting to think about.

Answer (score 9):

Is the purpose to prevent other software from working poorly because ffmpeg is hogging CPU in the background?

In that case I recommend running it with higher niceness instead:

```
nice -n 19 ffmpeg -i 50fps.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 30fps.mp4
```

This will allow the scheduler to minimize priority of ffmpeg and immediately preempt it in case any other process needs CPU, and still allows you to utilize all cores to encode as fast as possible.

Comment: It can make sense to limit number of threads to only the number of *physical* cores your CPU has, if it has 2 logical cores (SMT) for every physical.  I've found with x265 that interactive use on GNU/Linux is affected much less by `pools=4` on my 4c8t Skylake i7-6700k than by the default (starting at least as many threads as logical cores). Only gives up about 15% encode throughput. The benefit to other processes is from consuming less memory bandwidth and cache footprint, which `nice` doesn't help with; I've tried that in the past, and Chromium page loads and stuff were still noticeably slow.

Comment: x264 defaults to `threads = 1.5 * cores`, so maybe `threads = 6` on a 4c8t machine would be worth trying, or 5, or 4.  Some tradeoff between max encode throughput at your chosen `-preset medium -crf 23` or whatever vs. friendliness to other tasks.

Comment: Nice is nice, but with all cores maxed out it still noticeably affects other CPU-intensive processes as @PeterCordes says. Scheduling, context switching, etc. There's always overhead there.

Comment: The issue might be I/O (especially if bottleneck is HDD seek time); `ionice` (in addition to `nice`) might help with that.

Comment: @MatijaNalis: That's very unlikely when input and output are both using lossy compression (like in this case.)  `ffmpeg` writing a `.mp4` will by default encoding with `libx264`, which defaults to `-preset medium -crf 23`. And transcodes the audio, too, to AAC, because the OP didn't specify `-c:a copy`.  On a quad-core Skylake i7-6700k at 3.9GHz, for example, it encodes about 53 fps on some random 1080p video, the output file write averaged 651 Kbytes/second, over 3 minutes.  The input file read bandwidth was only a couple times that.  I/O could be an issue if reading lossless png or Y4M.

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg-only solution without nice/taskset/cpulimit/cgroups/docker:

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i 50fps.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 -threads 1 30fps.mp4
```

The position of `-threads 1` (and its count) does matter.

ffmpeg command has the [following format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis):

```
ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_file_options] -i input_url} ... {[output_file_options] output_url} ...
```

In your command with `-threads 1` before `-i` a single thread will be used for decoding of `50fps.mp4` but also you need to specify the number of threads for video encoding (after `-i`):

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i 50fps.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 -threads 1 30fps.mp4
```

Also you may need to [check out](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) `-filter_threads` or `-filter_complex_threads` in case of filter_complex graphs.

Comment: Unintuitive, but this does work! For me 1 decoding + 1 encoding thread basically uses a single core. With 2 encoding threads the load is 60-70% evenly on all 4 cores which I want to avoid. Taskset seems a better solution overall.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Linux distribution which uses systemd, then you can use one if its utilities named *systemd-run* for resource control. For your case, it would be this:

```
sudo systemd-run --scope -p AllowedCPUs=VALUE CMD
sudo systemd-run --scope -p CPUQuota=VALUE% CMD
```

For `AllowedCPUs`, you can mention the indice of the logical core to which you want to restrict the execution of your command. Indice is 0 for first logical core, 1 for second logical core, and so on.

For `CPUQuota`, 100% equals one logical core's *maximum* available CPU time. 200% would be two logical cores, and so on.

Example A:

```
# My stress commands wants to use all 8 logical cores of my machine, 
# but systemd would limit it to allowed logical cores 0 and 4. 
# I chose 0 and 4 because both belongs to the same physical core.

sudo systemd-run --scope -p AllowedCPUs=0,4 stress -c 8
```

Example B:

```
# Here, my stress command despite being hungry for all CPUs would only
get 100% *available* time of one logical core only.

sudo systemd-run --scope CPUQuota=100% stress -c 8
```

Suggested readings: manual of [systemd-run](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html) and [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

Answer (score 1):

I routinely use cpulimit to throttle the overall burden on my machine with nightly LARGE compressed backups, such as the following:

```
{ sleep 1 ; tar -zcf output.tar.gz /mnt/3TBNumber3C/HUGE_dir ; killall cpulimit ; } & cpulimit -e /bin/gzip -l 30
```

I wondered what the difference was between cpulimit and taskset and I gather from [this site](http://tuxdiary.com/2014/09/03/cpulimit-taskset/) that cpulimit is a throttle whereas taskset establishes affinities. Indeed, if I am up late enough I can actually hear my cooling fans going up and down so that the overall **average** load on the CPU cores is 30 percent (in the above example).

I have also used this to throttle ffmpeg for the same reason as the questioner asked, though I am usually doing that "hands on".